# Is $f:\Bbb Q\rightarrow \Bbb R$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Define $f:Q\rightarrow R$ such that $f= 1$ if  $x^2<2$  or  $f=0$ is  $x^2>2 $. Is this function continuous? All proofs are welcomed but i am more interested using the definitions  maybe the definition that the preimage of a continuous function sis an  οpen set or the ε,δ definition.My problem is that these definitions are for a single point.How can i use the definitions for every point?Trying to practice on using definitions and get a better understanding for continuity rather than that the graph of f is interrupted or has "holes".

Comment: The only "problems" are at $\pm\sqrt{2}$ (because everywhere else, you can find a neighbourhood where your function is constant so your function is continuous). Now, let's take a sequence $(u_n)_n$ that converges in $\mathbb{Q}$. To prove that $f$ is continuous, you just need to show that $f(u_n)$ converges (for $u$ arbitrary). But since $u_n$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}$, it can't converge to $\pm\sqrt{2}$ so you're "far enough" from the "problems".

Comment: "Sending open sets to open sets" is not a valid definition of a continuous function - for instance, $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, but the image of $(-1,1)$ is $[0,1)$ which isn't open. You may have confused the definition with "preimages of open sets are open." This is a very important fact - you might want to review what this means.

Comment: @MiloBrandt You are right thanks for noticing .And that was one of the reasons i was confused in my proofs!!!!!

Comment: @xavierm02 You mean that in an neighbourhood near $sqrt(2)$ is the only neighbour i have to decide whether  f is continuous .But x never goes close to that  neighbourhood. So i do not have to care at all.

Comment: @ManolisLyviakis Yes. The only problems are with neighbourhoods of $\pm\sqrt{2}$ but since your sequence can't get arbitrarily close to $\pm\sqrt{2}$, by taking a small enough neighbourhood of $\pm\sqrt{2}$, you can make it so that all your sequence is outside of it, and so you avoid the "problem".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is continuous.

One way to see this is by using the fact that $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous in $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, the sets $A=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 <2\}, B=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 >2\} $ are open. Since the pre-images of open sets of your function $f$ are $A,B,\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: why $x-->x^2$ is continuous in $Q$? And  how you get from  that to that A and B are Open.I can see that they are open since there is no maximum point in them or minimum for B. BUt i want the full rigorous analysis using definitions to get the thinking.Also these 2 sets Are subsets of Q and say we proved that they are open .For $f$ to be continuous  the open sets that contain $f(x0)$ there must be corresponding open sets in Q .How i know that A,B correspond to  all Open sets that contain $f(x0)$

Comment: 1 - $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous because is the restriction of a continuous function (I'm assuming you know $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous in the real numbers... if you don't know, you surely know the identity is and the multiplication of continuous function is continuous, so there it is.)
2 - $A,B$ are open because they are the preimage of open sets (namely, $(2, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 2)$
3 - For a function to be ("globally") continuous it suffices to prove that the preimages of open sets are open. This is a fundamental fact of continuity, and surely you have that on your textbook.

Comment: ohh so what you did is  that since $x^2$ is continuous every open subset of R the preimage of this is open in Q.So for the subsets (2,+00) (-00,2) the preimages are Open in Q which means the sets $A={x|x^2<2}$ and $B{x|x^2>2}$ are Open .And since the preimages of any open set of R of my function is either the empty set or A or B or Q  then f is continuous .thanks very much i understood alot of things.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a some direction for the kind of proof I think you are looking for:

$f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined so that $f(x) = 1$ for $x^2 < 2$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x^2 > 2$. We would like to show that $f$ is continuous.

In other words, we need to show that $f$ is continuous at any point $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. Because $\sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, we can think of two exhaustive and exclusive cases: $a^2 > 2$ and $a^2 < 2$. I will show how to handle the first case, the second is similar.

Assume $a^2 > 2$. Then by the [density of the rationals in the reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494681/density-of-rationals-and-irrationals-in-real-analysis), there must exist another number $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt{2} < b < a$. Let $\varepsilon = a-b$. Now, by the definition of $f$, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ within $\varepsilon$ of $a$ (i.e. the "ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $a$").

Can you finish the proof using the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition of continuity of $f$ at $a$?

<sup>(I tried to keep this proof as self-contained as possible, but I did use the fact that the rationals are dense in the reals. For the purposes of this proof that means that there is a rational number strictly between any two real numbers. A proofs on MSE are provided in the link.)</sup>

Comment: One way to get around using the density of the rationals in the reals is to notice that, if $a$ is positive at $a^2>2$ then $b=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{a}2$ has $b<a$ and $b^2>2$. Similarly, if $a$ is positive at $a^2<0$ then $b=(2-a^2)/3 + a$ has $b>a$ and $b^2<2$. Of course, these facts too need proof and it's mostly just finicky algebra (or calculus works as well)

Comment: Thank you for a proof of ε,δ  i was looking for one like this but mostly one with open sets.So i am gonna upvote your answer but i can only accept one answer.

Answer (score -2):

Realize that your function f is continuous in R. Therefore, it is definitely continuous on a subset of R, which Q is. This is what you call f restricted to Q. Also, from a metric space standpoint, we know that Q is not a closed set since its complement R\Q is not open (you can prove this easily). Therefore, just use the definition of continuity as you pointed out. Take any open set, its pre image will be in Q, which is not closed.

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$? It's not even defined on all of $\mathbb R$! (And, more substantially, it can't be continuously extended to $\mathbb R$)